An entire map $f$ such that $\liminf \limits_{\lvert z \rvert \to \infty} \lvert f(z) \rvert \gt 0$ is a polynomial
I want to prove that an entire map $f$ such that $\liminf \limits_{\lvert z \rvert \to \infty} \lvert f(z) \rvert \gt 0$ is a polynomial.
As $f$ is entire, we can write $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$. I'm trying to prove that the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ eventually vanishes, which is equivalent saying that $f$ is a polynomial. For this, I'm looking to use Cauchy's inequalities. But I cannot relate those to $\liminf \limits_{\lvert z \rvert \to \infty} \lvert f(z) \rvert$.

I don't know if this is the quickest way, but here's an outline of one approach:

The assumption implies that there exists $R>0$ so that $f(z)$ is bounded away from $0$ when $|z|>R$. In particular, $1/f(z)$ is bounded when $|z|>R$.
Furthermore, $f(z)$ has finitely many zeros on $|z|\le R$. Therefore there is a polynomial $p(z)$ such that $p(z)/f(z)$ is entire.
And $|p(z)/f(z)|$ then has only polynomial growth as $|z|\to\infty$....


Thank you Greg for the answer. I can follow each bullet point... But I don't understand how the desired conclusion follows.

@mathcounterexamples.net an entire function which grows polynomially is a polynomial; the proof is via Cauchy’s inequalities. So, there is a polynomial $q(z)$ such that $\frac{p(z)}{f(z)}=q(z)$, and thus $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$. This looks like a rational function, but $f$ is entire, so it’s actually a polynomial (i.e all the zeros in the denominator must be cancelled out by those in the numerator).

Here is another view: for entire functions, there are three types:
(1) constant functions ($\iff \infty$ is removable)
(2) polynomials with degree $n\geq1$ ($\iff\infty$ is a ploe of order $n$)
(3) transcendental entire functions ($\iff \infty$ is essential singularity)
If $\liminf \limits_{\lvert z \rvert \to \infty} \lvert f(z) \rvert \gt 0$, $f$ cann't be the thrid type, because $\infty$ is essential singularity,
then $f(V(\infty))$ is dense in $\mathbb C$, and we can choose $\{z_n\}$ with $z_n\to\infty$ and $f(z_n)\to0$. Here $V(\infty)$ is any nbd of $\infty$.
